# In-app purchase and version of the app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a paid App in the App store and would like to add In-App purchases to it, progressively in time (that is, put one Product now, one product next month, etc) but I wonder:

Do I have to handle the case where the user sees the product but is not allowed to purchase it because it needs a newer version of the app or does Apple only show In-App purchases that are available for the installed version in the user's device?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always add `in app purchases` to the app and show different purchases to different users depending on their app version or other configurations.

I have developed multiple apps to the app store where the clients depending on the version of the apps have access to different purchases. Though you will have to handle somewhere on the code which purchases you want to show for an specific version.

Answer (score 0):

No, that cannot happen. If you add a product to the app you need to add it somewhere where the user sees it and buys it. Users with an old version wont have that view.